# Ansible nested loop over hostvars

Tags: loops, ansible

I am trying to loop over all of the hosts that I've in the host_vars folder and get their corresponding interfaces, the interfaces var itself is a list.

problem: I can access the host_vars and get the desired data, except that the interface variable is a list and I want to loop over it.

What it looks like:

1. Loop through host_vars
2. Get the first host on the list
3. Loop over the interfaces
4. Repeat

To simplify things I am using debug in my example:

```yaml
- name: TEST_101
  debug:
    var: 
      hostvars[item]['interfaces'][X]['name']
  loop: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

`X`: is the corresponding interface index

The following are two of the host_vars files.

- *core_01*

  ```yaml
  ---
  ansible_host: 192.168.1.202
  site: XX-DC
  role: CORE
  model: CSR1000v 

  interfaces:
    - name: vlan 1
      description: "EDGE_RTR IF" 
      ipv4: 192.168.100.3/24
      state: merged
      enabled: true

    - name: vlan 100
      description: "IT IF"
      ipv4: 172.31.1.1/24
      state: merged
      enabled: true
  ```
- *core_02*

  ```yaml
  ---
  ansible_host: 192.168.12.210

  interfaces:
    - name: ethernet 0/0
      description: "ISP_01 IF PRIMARY"  #The discription on the interface
      ipv4: 10.0.0.2/24
      state: merged
      enabled: true

    - name: ethernet 0/1
      description: "CORE_SW IF PRIMARY" #The discription on the interface
      ipv4: 192.168.100.1/24
      state: merged
      enabled: true
  ```

The output when the script is run:

```
PLAY [Populate NetBox DataBase] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [build_netbox_db : Create interface within Netbox with only required information] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=edge_01) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "hostvars[item]['interfaces'][0]['name']": "ethernet 0/0",
    "item": "edge_01"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=edge_02) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "hostvars[item]['interfaces'][0]['name']": "ethernet 0/0",
    "item": "edge_02"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=csr1k_01) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "hostvars[item]['interfaces'][0]['name']": "ethernet 0/0",
    "item": "csr1k_01"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=core_01) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "hostvars[item]['interfaces'][0]['name']": "vlan 1",
    "item": "core_01"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

`X` is replaced with an index number.
In a sense, I want to loop twice, once over the host, then over the interfaces of that particular host.

Comment: Looping over `groups['all']` is usually a bad practice. Simply target the `all` group in your play. Ansible will naturally loop over the machines in that group. You then only need a task looping over `interfaces`

Comment: the target is supposed to be local as I am pushing config to netbox

Comment: @notomera then target `all` and [`delegate_to: 127.0.0.1`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks)

Comment: Same problem there is still the paradox of the two loops

Comment: That's the part I didn't get, to be honest. As soon as `all` is targeted, then, Ansible "naturally" loops on hosts. You just have to `loop: "{{ interfaces }}` and you can access `item.name`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you [delegate the task back to your local](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks), then you don't need to loop on the `groups['all']` anymore, and you can let Ansible do the normal process of targeting all the hosts defined in the `hosts` directive.

Then, you just have to loop on the `interfaces` variable of all hosts.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: core_01,core_02 
  ## I am limiting myslef to two hosts here, 
  ## but `all` would do just fine if you want to target all
  ## hosts in your inventory
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ interfaces }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

This will yield the recap:

```
PLAY [core_01,core_02] ********************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [core_01] => (item=vlan 1) => 
  msg: vlan 1
ok: [core_01] => (item=vlan 100) => 
  msg: vlan 100
ok: [core_02] => (item=ethernet 0/0) => 
  msg: ethernet 0/0
ok: [core_02] => (item=ethernet 0/1) => 
  msg: ethernet 0/1

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
core_01                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
core_02                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```